# Clicking to make a div appear and making it go away upon clicking again

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this piece of jquery code I'm trying to figure out - totally lost. It's super messy and I'm hoping someone can help me figure this out.

Basically I want to click "Hi" and have the second div slide down - when I click "Hi" again, I want the second div to slide back up. It's probably something easy... but for some reason I just can't wrap my mind around Jquery >

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#hi").click(function () {
    $("#one").toggle(function() {
      $(this).fadeIn("slow", function() {
        $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");
        });
      }); 

    });
});

});
```

And here is the [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/unusuw/1/) - Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not bind another click event handler inside the first click event handler, all you really need is `fadeToggle` if you are trying to fade the second element in and out :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#hi").click(function () {
        $("#one").fadeToggle(); 
    });
});
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ucepur/1/edit)

Comment: I love you Adeneo. Don't forget that. Ever.

Comment: `.slideToggle()` might be another option too.